# Where is the source code for the sequence expression builder

Tags: f#

I'm curious how the F# Seq computational expression implements the IEnumerable data structure.

Searching [Sharp.Core/seq.fs](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/seq.fs) on GitHub for the implementation of yield! ( YieldFrom(expr) ) isn't successful.

Comment: I revised the title. The `seq` **operator** is used for casting to `seq<'T>` ([see source](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/prim-types.fs#L3515)).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As the specification quoted by Daniel says, sequence expressions are not treated as ordinary computation expressions - rather than translating them to builder method calls (such as `seq.For`, `seq.Yield` etc.), the compiler actually generates code that is specific for sequences. This is mainly for performance reasons - the calls to computation builder would add too much overhead.

Here are two relevant pointers:

- The `GeneratedSequenceBase` type is the base class that is used by the compiler when compiling sequence expressions - there is also other library code around it that is used by the generated compiled code. See [the F# library source code here](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/8c82d57a6e8cc131740316b00f199d9d48072346/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/seq.fs#L747).
- The `TcSequenceExpression` method in the type checker is where the type checking happens. You can see that the compiler is following a different path than for ordinary computation expressions. This is [here in the compiler source code](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/tc.fs#L7479).
- The other relevant parts are in `ilxgen.fs` where the compiler actually generates the code after type checking - you can find the places by looking for `GeneratedSequenceBase` in the source code (but I'm not an expert on this part)

Comment: If you feel like it please come and visit us in [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51909/f)

Answer (score 3):

See §6.3.11 of the [spec](http://fsharp.org/specs/language-spec/3.0/FSharpSpec-3.0-final.pdf). It states:

> Logically speaking, sequence expressions can be thought of as computation expressions with a builder of type `Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.SeqBuilder`....However, this builder type is not actually defined in the F# library.

It goes on to show exactly how sequence expressions are elaborated by the compiler.